# Remote computer provisioning fails: unable to create directory

Tags: windows, driver, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug a device driver using a host (x86) laptop and an x64 desktop target, both running Windows 10.

I follow the instructions to configure the target from Visual Studio Community 2015 on the laptop. It creates and opens a WDKRemoteUser account on the target.
The host then reports that it cannot create C:\DriverText\Setup and the provisioning fails.

Looking at the target PC, I can see that C:\DriverText\Setup has indeed been created and seems to have the relevant permissions. The drive has gigabytes of free space.

Any suggestions as to what is going wrong?

The start of the host log is as follows (I assume the rest is irrelevant after the first error):

Name: Install Driver Test Components
  Path: C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\WDKTestInfrastructure\InfrastructureTaskGroups\Install Driver Test Components.xml
  Target Computer: New Computer
Install Driver Test Components: Host Computer: PETER-10-LAPTOP
Install Driver Test Components: Host Architecture: x86
Install Driver Test Components: Host 64bit Operating System: False
Install Driver Test Components: Host Operating System Version: 10.0.10586.0
Install Driver Test Components: Process Administrator Privilege: False
Progress event: Current: 1, Max: 14, Message: ""
Progress event: Current: 1, Max: 14, Message: "Copying required files"
[15:31:35:936]: Copying required files
[15:31:35:947]: Task "Copying required files" was aborted because an error occured on the target machine during execution.

An error occurred on the target machine while copying a file from the host machine.
Error code: 0
Error message: Unable to create directory: C:\DriverTest\Setup.
Progress event: Current: 1, Max: 14, Message: "    Task "Copying required files" was aborted because an error occured on the target machine during execution.

An error occurred on the target machine while copying a file from the host machine.
Error code: 0
Error message: Unable to create directory: C:\DriverTest\Setup."
Task result status updated: Aborted
Result completed
Test process exit code: 0

Comment: I assume that your "C:\DriverTe_x_t\" is a typo?